# How can I find the average of 3 date in Ruby on rails or Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I find the average of 3 date in Ruby on rails or Ruby ? **like bellow.**

**(Date1 + Date2 + Date3)/3**

Comment: To be clear, are you using **DATES** or **TIMES**? These are different objects, and you probably expect a different result depending on the answer to this question.

Comment: The "average" of three *times* is fairly well-defined. But to get the "average" of three dates, you may need to "round up/down"; and the requirements for this are not clear in your question.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71502116/edit) to give an example using real values, and potentially highlight how you wish to handle significant edge cases (if there are any!).

Comment: you can refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2288224/17983466

Answer (score 4):

If you convert the dates to integers with `.to_i` you can do the average exactly as you suggested.  Then use `.at` to get back to a datetime.

```rb
d1 = Time.now
=> 2022-03-16 11:07:12 -0700

d2 = Time.now - 10000
=> 2022-03-16 08:20:32 -0700

d3 = Time.now - 30000
=> 2022-03-16 02:47:12 -0700

Time.at((d1.to_i + d2.to_i + d3.to_i)/3)
=> 2022-03-16 07:24:58 -0700
```

Comment: You can also use `to_r` for sub-second precision.

Comment: This is working for Date.tody and Date.tommorrow and Date.yesterday and Date.today-1000 ..... but its not works when i get the database convert to integer and doing caluclation and again converting to time its giving the date as 01/01/1970 05:30:00

Comment: @Nagendra _"This is working for Date.today and ..."_ – if this code works fine for Ruby's built-in classes, you might consider accepting it as it seems to answer your question (which didn't specify any specific database format). The conversion of your database fields to / from `Date` or `Time` instances seems to be a problem on its own. You could maybe ask that in a separate follow-up question.

Answer (score 0):

```
first_date = Date.today.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_i
second_date = Date.tomorrow.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_i
third_date = Date.yesterday.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_i

average_date = (first_date + second_date + third_date) / 3

Date.parse(average_date.to_s) OR Time.at(average_date)
```

Comment: This is working for Date.tody and Date.tommorrow and Date.yesterday and Date.today-1000 .....

but its not works when i get the database convert to integer and doing caluclation and again converting to time its giving the date as 01/01/1970 05:30:00

Comment: Date and time calculation doesn't work like that. If you have January 1st and February 1st as integers, i.e. `2022_01_01` and `2022_02_01` (underscores added for clarity), their numeric average is `2022_01_51`. Apparently, that's not a valid date anymore. You could use the Julian day number instead, see [`Date#jd`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-jd).

Answer (score -4):

If you are working with Date objects (Not Time nor DateTime) you can easily calculate the middle date between 3 (or even more dates if you add them to the array).

Imagine you have your dates in an array:

```
dates = [Date.today, 1.day.ago, 10.days.ago]
difference = dates.max - dates.min
average_date = dates.min + difference/2
```

Basically, we're getting the days difference between the higher date value and the minimum date value, then adding half that difference to the smallest date, and there you have the average date between the 3, the date in the middle won't change anything so it's not being used with this approach.

Comment: In the OP's **(Date1 + Date2 + Date3)/3** pseudocode, every value matters.

Comment: @Stefan I meant it doesn't matter if you get the difference between the min and max dates, I didn't mention that pseudocode.

Comment: Indeed you didn't mention it. But the OP basically asks how to calculate `(1 + 2 + 9)/3` and you suggest doing `(1 + 9)/2` instead. That just doesn't seem right.

Comment: From what I can see, the OP asks how to find the average of 3 dates, and I answered exactly that. If you don't like my answer I'm really sorry.